# compute the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_{0}^{x^3}1-\cos t \ dt}{x^3}$

Tags: calculus

How can I compute the next limit

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_{0}^{x^3}1-\cos t \ dt}{x^3}$$

Any hint or idea.

Or any advise to compute the next Limit?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i-3}{n^2}$$

Comment: LHopital's rule

Answer (score 3):

Notice, we are in the situation where we have $\frac{0}{0}$, thus one applies Lhopitals rule:

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ 3x^2(1 - \cos x^3) }{x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0 } 3(1-\cos x^3) = 0$$

Comment: May be, you could precise in your good answer that we need to use the FTC first.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_{0}^{x^3}(1-\cos t) \ dt}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(t-\sin t)\Big{|}_{0}^{x^3}}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^3-\sin x^3}{x^3}$$
set $u=x^3$, we have
$$I=\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{u-\sin u}{u}=\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\frac16 u^3}{u}=0$$

---

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i-3}{n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}i-\sum_{i=1}^{n}3\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-3n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2-5n}{2n^2}=\frac12$$